# Geodesics and Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, laplacian, eigenfunctions

**For a smooth, closed Riemannian 2-manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, is there a relationship between the geodesics of $M$ and smooth functions $k : M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ which can be expressed in terms of outer products of eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_M$?**

Let $(\lambda_j, \phi_j)$ be eigenpairs of $\Delta_M$, so that
$$ -\Delta_M \phi_j = \lambda_j \phi_j. $$
Then define
$$ k(x_1, x_2) = \sum_j \alpha(\lambda_j) \phi_j(x_1) \overline{\phi_j(x_2)} $$
for some nonnegative function $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$. Let $d(x_1, x_2)$ be the geodesic distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$. **Is it true that $k$ is "stationary in geodesic distance" in the sense that for all $x_1, x_2 \in M$ we have $k(x_1, x_2) = f\big(d(x_1, x_2)\big)$ for some $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ ?**

For closed curves $\Gamma$ (i.e. 1-manifolds) of length $2\pi$, I believe these notions are equivalent. Let $s$ and $t$ denote arclengths on $\Gamma$. Here the Laplace-Beltrami operator is simply the Laplacian, whose eigenfunctions are $e^{ijs}$. So any continuous function $k: \Gamma \times \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ that can be written as
\begin{align}
  k\big(x(s), x(t)\big) 
  &= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \alpha(j^2) e^{ijs} \overline{e^{ijt}} \\ 
  &= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \alpha(j^2) e^{ij(s-t)} \\
  &= f(s-t)
\end{align}
is stationary in geodesic distance.

I also believe that these notions are equivalent for the sphere $S^2$. Let $\theta$ be the great circle distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Here the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator are spherical harmonics $Y_{jm}$, and it can be shown using some Bessel function identities [1, Section 3] that
\begin{align}
  k(x_1, x_2) 
  &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-j}^j \alpha\big(j(j+1)\big) Y_{jm}(x_1) \overline{Y_{jm}(x_2)} \\
  &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2j+1}{4\pi} \alpha\big(j(j+1)\big) P_j(\cos \theta) \\
  &= f(\theta)
\end{align}
is stationary in geodesic distance, where $P_j$ is a Legendre polynomial.

So my question is - **does this phenomenon generalize to arbitrary smooth manifolds? or is it a coincidence of constant curvature?**

My only idea so far is to look at geodesics as a surface heat flow problem, whose solution is governed by the Laplace-Beltrami operator... Any references or suggestions are appreciated!

1. Lang, Annika, and Christoph Schwab. "Isotropic Gaussian random fields on the sphere: regularity, fast simulation and stochastic partial differential equations." (2015): 3047-3094.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is even about constant curvature. The sphere is a highly symmetric object. What about a right circular cylinder? It's locally isometric to the plane, but not globally so.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's true - it could be due to some other symmetry of the sphere. The right circular cylinder isn't closed though, and I'm not sure what boundary condition to impose... maybe an ellipsoid or torus is a simpler first example to explore?

Comment: Sorry — I missed the closed. Geodesics on the flat torus might be good to explore, but that comes from an embedding in $\Bbb R^4$.